# How to handle array state filter clashes

Tags: arrays, reactjs, asynchronous, filter, state

I am currently having an issue where multiple setStates that use the filtering of an array are interfering with each other. Basically if a user uploads two files, and they complete around the same time, one of the incomplete files may fail to be filtered from the array.

My best guess is that this is happening because they are separately filtering out the one that needs to be filtered, when the second one finishes and goes to filter itself out of the array, it still has the copy of the old incomplete array where the first file has not been filtered out yet. What would be a better way to approach this? Am I missing something obvious? I am thinking of using an object to hold the files instead, but then I would need to create a custom mapping function for the rendering part so that it can still be rendered as if were an array.

```js
fileHandler = (index, event) =>{
    let incompleteFiles = this.state.incompleteFiles
    incompleteFiles[index].loading = true
    incompleteFiles[index].file = event.target.files[0]
    this.setState({ incompleteFiles: incompleteFiles },()=>{
            const fileData = new FormData()
            fileData.append('file', event.targets[0].file)
            let incompleteFiles = this.state.incompleteFiles
            let completeFiles = this.state.completeFiles
                api.uploadFile(fileData)
                    .then(res=>{
                        if(res.data.success){
                            this.setState(state=>{
                                let completeFile = {
                                    name : res.data.file.name,
                                }
                                completeFiles.push(completeFile)
                                incompleteFiles = incompleteFiles.filter(inc=>inc.label !== res.data.file.name)
                                return{
                                    completeFiles,
                                    incompleteFiles
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    })
        })
    }
```

Updated with accepted answer with a minor tweak

```
fileHandler = (index, event) =>{
    this.setState(({ incompleteFiles }) => ({       
    //  Update the state in an immutable way.       
        incompleteFiles: [              
            ...incompleteFiles.slice(0, index),              
            {                
                ...incompleteFiles[index],                
                loading: true,                
                file: event.target.files[0],              
            },              
            ...incompleteFiles.slice(index+1)       
        ],     
    }),  () => {
      const fileData = new FormData()
      fileData.append('file', event.targets[0].file)
      api.uploadFile(fileData)
        .then(res => {
          if(res.data.success){
              this.setState(({ incompleteFiles, completeFiles }) => ({
                completeFiles: [
                  ...completeFiles, // Again, avoiding the .push since it mutates the array.
                  { // The new file.
                    name: res.data.file.name,
                  }
                ],
                incompleteFiles: incompleteFiles.filter(inc=>inc.label !== res.data.file.name),
              })))
          }
        })
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In class components in React, when setting the state which *is derived from the current state*, you should always pass a "state updater" function instead of just giving it an object of state to update.

```js
//  Bad
this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1 });

// Good
this.setState((currentState) => ({ counter: currentState.counter + 1 }));
```

This ensures that you are getting the most up-to-date version of the state. The fact that this is needed is a side-effect of how React pools state updates under the hood (which makes it more performant).

I think if you were to re-write your code to make use of this pattern, it would be something like this:

```js
fileHandler = (index, event) =>{
    this.setState(({ incompleteFiles }) => ({
      //  Update the state in an immutable way.
      incompleteFiles: {
        [index]: {
          ...incompleteFiles[index],
          loading: true,
          file: event.target.files[0],
        },
      },
    }), () => {
      const fileData = new FormData()
      fileData.append('file', event.targets[0].file)
      api.uploadFile(fileData)
        .then(res => {
          if(res.data.success){
              this.setState(({ incompleteFiles, completeFiles }) => ({
                completeFiles: [
                  ...completeFiles, // Again, avoiding the .push since it mutates the array.
                  { // The new file.
                    name: res.data.file.name,
                  }
                ],
                incompleteFiles: incompleteFiles.filter(inc=>inc.label !== res.data.file.name),
              })))
          }
        })
    });
  }
```

Another thing to keep in mind is to avoid mutating your state objects. Methods like [`Array.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) will mutate the array *in-place*, which can cause issues and headaches.

Comment: this works pretty well, I did have to modify the part for updating the state of the object in the array slightly to 
```javascript

this.setState(({ incompleteFiles }) => ({
      //  Update the state in an immutable way.
      incompleteFiles: [
             ...incompleteFiles.slice(0, index),
             {
               ...incompleteFiles[index],
               loading: true,
               file: event.target.files[0],
             },
             ...incompleteFiles.slice(index+1)
      ],
    })

```

Answer (score 0):

I think change code to this can solve your problem and make code easy to read.

```js
fileHandler = async (index, event) =>{
    const incompleteFiles = [...this.state.incompleteFiles]
    incompleteFiles[index].loading = true
    incompleteFiles[index].file = event.target.files[0]

    this.setState(
      {
        incompleteFiles
      },
      async (prev) => {
        const fileData = new FormData()
        fileData.append('file', event.targets[0].file)

        const res = await api.uploadFile(fileData)

        /// set loading state to false
        incompleteFiles[index].loading = false
        
        if (!res.data.success) {
          return { ...prev, incompleteFiles }
        }

        // add new file name into completeFiles and remove uploaded file name from incompleteFiles
        return {
          ...prev,
          completeFiles: [...prev.completeFiles, { name : res.data.file.name }],
          incompleteFiles: incompleteFiles.filter(inc=>inc.label !== res.data.file.name)
        }
      })
    )
}
```